# Reading multiple parameters of JSON objects in java

Tags: java, jsonreader

Hi guys I am getting issue while reading this file can anyone suggest me how to read this file by using model name and tagline and also variant code of this model. I am new to reading in json using java , whenever I am trying to read getting this exception i.e. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to class org.json.simple.JSONArray (org.json.simple.JSONObject and org.json.simple.JSONArray are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
Any reference for this?

```
    {
      "models": {
        "IN": [
          {
            "modelName": "Inter",
            "modelTagline": "A classic  roadster",
            "models": [
              {
                "ID": "Inter-0",
                "engineCapacity": "Test",
                "imageUrl": "INT.png",
                "mailCCBTR": "",
                "mailToBTR": "",
                "mailerBikeImageBTR": "orange.jpg",
                "modelCodeBTR": "XYZ23",
                "name": "Int 0",
                "power": "47 Bhp",
                "showCatalogue": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tagLine": "A classic roadster",
                "torque": "52 Nm",
                "variants": [
                  {
                    "highlights": [
                      "LOREM IPSUM",
                      "",
                      "",
                      ""
                    ],
                    "id": "int 50",
                    "imageUrl": "3F_GTred_000.png",
                    "name": "red",
                    "showBookNow": false,
                    "showConfigureNow": true,
                    "showInDealer": false,
                    "showInREPrime": true,
                    "tankColor": "Red",
                    "tankImage": "Red_01.png",
                    "variantCode": "AVC",
                    "webp": "000.webp",
                    "webp-mobile-1x": "3.webp",
                    "webp-mobile-2x": "2.webp"
                  },
                  {
                    "highlights": [
                      "LOREM IPSUM",
                      "",
                      "",
                      ""
                    ],
                    "id": "int 50",
                    "imageUrl": "V000.png",
                    "name": "Blue",
                    "showBookNow": false,
                    "showConfigureNow": true,
                    "showInDealer": false,
                    "showInREPrime": true,
                    "tankColor": "Blue",
                    "tankImage": "Blue_01.png",
                    "variantCode": "SADSAD32",
                    "webp": "F.webp",
                    "webp-mobile-1x": "LOREM IPSUM.webp",
                    "webp-mobile-2x": "LOREM IPSUM.webp"
                  },
                  {
                    "highlights": [
                      "LOREM IPSUM",
                      "",
                      "",
                      ""
                    ],
                    "id": "int 50",
                    "imageUrl": "80.png",
                    "name": "Crush",
                    "showBookNow": false,
                    "showConfigureNow": true,
                    "showInDealer": false,
                    "showInREPrime": true,
                    "tankColor": "Crush",
                    "tankImage": "h_01.png",
                    "variantCode": "56565SDGFS",
                    "webp": "h_000.webp",
                    "webp-mobile-1x": "LOREM IPSUM.webp",
                    "webp-mobile-2x": "LOREM IPSUM.webp"
                  },
                  {
                    "highlights": [
                      "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                      "",
                      "",
                      ""
                    ],
                    "id": "inter50",
                    "imageUrl": "00.png",
                    "name": "Downtown Drag",
                    "showBookNow": false,
                    "showConfigureNow": true,
                    "showInDealer": false,
                    "showInREPrime": true,
                    "tankColor": "Downtown Drag",
                    "tankImage": "01.png",
                    "variantCode": "lkasdsd",
                    "webp": "int 500.webp",
                    "webp-mobile-1x": "int 500.webp",
                    "webp-mobile-2x": "test.webp"
                  },
                  {
                    "highlights": [
                      "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                      "",
                      "",
                      ""
                    ],
                    "id": "int 50",
                    "imageUrl": "k_000.png",
                    "name": "Sunset Strip",
                    "showBookNow": false,
                    "showConfigureNow": true,
                    "showInDealer": false,
                    "showInREPrime": true,
                    "tankColor": "Sunset Strip",
                    "tankImage": "Black_01.png",
                    "variantCode": "AFDF23",
                    "webp": "TEST.webp",
                    "webp-mobile-1x": "TEST3.webp",
                    "webp-mobile-2x": "T.webp"
                  }      
            ]
          
    }
```

Hi guys I am getting issue while reading this file can anyone suggest me how to read this file by using model name and tagline and also variant code of this model. I am new to reading in json using java , whenever I am trying to read getting this exception i.e. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to class org.json.simple.JSONArray (org.json.simple.JSONObject and org.json.simple.JSONArray are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: The json is invalid so fix that first I think and see what happens as it's possible it'll change the end result.  I use this site a bit -> [jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Answer (score 0):

looks like this json is not completed. If i have misunderstand, you can upload .json file. If this json is all, please append "]}]}}" to end of json.
Good luck.

Comment: Here I am putting a right form of json can someone help me out how to read parameters of the given json with java like Tank Color, Variant Code